# Automated screen pause reminder

Tags: time-management, productivity, health

Do you know of an existing application (e.g. for android) that automatically monitors how long you've been staring at your screen and suggests you to pause after a while ?

Pause reminder apps are common, but you'd often forget to hit "start", for example when you're answering to a text conversation.

One way of doing that would be by analysing front camera snaps, or the accelerometer for a cheaper approximation.

I believe it could be beneficial for our eyes, but our social life and productivity as well.

Comment: Well... I don't know for android but for windows/linux PC you could definitely give a try to [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/)

Comment: @danicotra - I think that's worth making into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer I found [Stretchly](https://hovancik.net/stretchly/) to be a very good option to have regular pauses. 
For mobiles, it looks like the next iPhone [could provide an API](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/8/9/16117954/iphone-8-silence-notifications-automatic-face-3d-sensor-rumor) to implement that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but maybe it will help you: You are describing a famous productivity technique. It is called Pomodoro ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique)). I am sure you find an app when searching for the term "Pomodoro". There are many web apps like [pomofocus.io](https://pomofocus.io/) which might be worth a try. Personally, I'm stuck with a real timer that's also easy to use while on the phone and that you don't forget as often (so a hardware recomandation for once).